# Typesetting a worksheet

Tags: tables, enumerate

I'm trying to create a very basic worksheet in TeX. I just want a document that gives some instructions and then lists a few problems in a grid, the same way you'd see in a math textbook for a precalculus course, for instance. I'd also like the problems to be numbered.

I was thinking of accomplishing this by using a table and enumerating the entries of the table. However the enumerate command doesn't seem to like being used in a table, so I'm not really sure what to do there. Also, my table is getting put at the bottom of the page for some reason.

Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\title{Worksheet \S 1.1}
\date{}
\author{}
\maketitle

Solve each equation and check your answer.

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
$3x-5=0$ & $-3x+6=12$ &  $8x-6=1-6x$ & $-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true the `tabular` and the `enumerate` environment of the `exam` class do not mix.  Here is a solution using the exam class with `multicol` vice `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\title{Worksheet \S 1.1}
\date{}
\author{}
\maketitle

Solve each equation and check your answer.
First usings a separate multicol environment for each row.\par 

\begin{questions}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\end{multicols}
\end{questions}

Now using only one multicol environment resulting in vertical numbering.

\begin{questions}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\question$3x-5=0$ 
\question$-3x+6=12$ 
\question$8x-6=1-6x$ 
\question$-\frac{3}{4}x=18$
\end{multicols}

\end{questions}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Output as follows:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I was resorting to using an inline enumeration hack with the tabto package for formatting, but this does all of that automatically!